# How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time ?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, boot, xubuntu, lubuntu

how do we get grub menu when boot up process?
 tried by using both shift and E s c keys

Answer (score 5):

To get into that menu you should simply press <kbd>shift</kbd> as soon the BIOS is done, this might need a few tries to get the timing right.

The other option is to edit grub itself for making it permanently appear you can open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

There you change this line

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

to

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

After that you need to update your grub bootloader with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, if my post helped you you can accept it by clicking on the check-mark beside it.

Comment: It only worked for me after commenting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`