# How to claim Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet

Ethernet and WiFi are being shown as unclaimed while running

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for gumby: 
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
    version: 07
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff
```

booting up in older version

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for gumby:
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    logical name: wlo1
    version: 01
    serial: 0c:84:dc:86:d9:70
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.13.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:33 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
    logical name: eno1
    version: 07
    serial: a0:48:1c:0b:29:53
    size: 100Mbit/s
    capacity: 100Mbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
    resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff

    rfkill list all
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo modprobe r8169
[sudo] password for gumby: 
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: Let's also see: `uname -r` Thanks.

Comment: 4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: If you interrupt the boot process and, at the GRUB menu, select an earlier kernel version than -32, does the ethernet work? Also, please show us: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf `

Comment: will try the boot. the cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf -- option iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

Comment: ok how do I get older versions? sorry don't remember

Comment: Like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775437/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: working now Thank you How do i make this permanent? and what is the best gui for wifi connections

Comment: Please see my answer in a few moments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we see this:

> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with
>   'option'

The file now reads:

> option iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

The file was erroneously overwritten. It should read:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Please restore the deleted content and then be certain the term is *options* with an s.

Next, as you found, when you boot into an earlier kernel version, the ethernet and, I assume, wireless, works as expected. Let's try to reinstall the -32 version.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic 
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic
```

Reboot. Is everything working correctly now?

Comment: sorry but back to the same no Ethernet but wireless is no longer showing unclaimed

Comment: When I open Wicd Network Manager it reads No wireless networks found

Comment: Is it blocked by the hardware switch? `rfkill list all` Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep iwl` What does this report? `sudo modprobe r8169`

Comment: @chili555 Do you know why we need to downgrade the linux kernel for this to work? I have 5.3, for example, so I don't know if it would be feasible for me to downgrade (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277732/getting-make-build-essential-and-ethernet-drivers-installed-on-ubuntu-18-04-ma)

Comment: @ComputerScientist I am not certain that it is still necessary. Please start a new question and we'll investigate.